# Pandas apply in parallel when axis=0

Tags: python, pandas, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing

I want to apply some function on all pandas columns in parallel. For example, I want to do this in parallel:

```
def my_sum(x, a):
    return x + a


df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]})
df.apply(lambda x: my_sum(x, 2), axis=0)
```

I know there is a `swifter` package, but it doesn't support `axis=0` in apply:

> NotImplementedError: Swifter cannot perform axis=0 applies on large
>   datasets. Dask currently does not have an axis=0 apply implemented.
>   More details at https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/issues/10

Dask also doesn't support this for `axis=0` (according to documentation in swifter).

I have googled several sources but couldn't find an easy solution.

Can't believe this is so complicated in pandas.

Comment: may be take a look at [`Pandarallel`](https://github.com/nalepae/pandarallel/tree/v1.4.6)

Comment: transpose the data and pass `axis=1`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, I thought about that, but I have lots of rows (> 4 million), not sure if this is the recommended way.

Comment: @anky_91, a have just tried Pandarallel. It gets stuck forever and never ends. Maybe there is some problem because I am on the windows. I can't believe it. In R there are at least 3 simple solutions to this.

Comment: https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter/pull/98 - maybe this is what you're looking for

Comment: @Skarlett, I don't need applymap function, but apply. That is, I have to apply function to whole column, not to every elemet of the column.

Comment: When asking a question here, please describe the problem you are trying to solve, rather than asking about the method you think is the solution to that problem. We'll tell you if a parallel apply is really the best solution to your problem. Bashing a framework for a lack of support of non-idiomatic use cases won't help either. More details about the function you are trying to apply would help.

Comment: My original problem is the same as in the post above. Only defference is that function is more complicated.

Comment: @cs95 why would you consider a column-wise apply to be non-idiomatic? Especially as `axis=0` is the default

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code/54432584#54432584 what function are you trying to apply is what I was getting at.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Comment: Try [`mapply`](https://pypi.org/project/mapply/) with `chunk_size=1` (author here). For axis=0, each column will need to go to a worker without splitting the column into chunks. So if you have multiple columns and multiple physical CPUs, `mapply` will send each column to a separate worker, and combine the results afterwards to yield the same result as a regular apply would.

Comment: this task is trivially solved using the parallel-pandas library

Answer (score 4):

[Koalas](https://databricks.com/blog/2019/04/24/koalas-easy-transition-from-pandas-to-apache-spark.html) provides a way to perform computation on a dataframe in parallel. It accepts the same commands as `pandas` but performs them on a Apache Spark engine in the background.

Note that you do need the parallel infrastructure available in order to use it properly.

On their blog post they compare the following chunks of code:

pandas:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2], 'y': [3, 4], 'z': [5, 6]})
# Rename columns
df.columns = [‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z1’]
# Do some operations in place
df[‘x2’] = df.x * df.x
```

Koalas:

```py
import databricks.koalas as ks
df = ks.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2], 'y': [3, 4], 'z': [5, 6]})
# Rename columns
df.columns = [‘x’, ‘y’, ‘z1’]
# Do some operations in place
df[‘x2’] = df.x * df.x
```

Comment: [pandas, PySpark, pyarrow, matplotlib](https://koalas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/install.html)

Comment: I will install PySpark and pyarrow, tried it and give you feedback

Comment: lot's of dependencies for such a "simple" task.

Comment: ks.from_pandas also freezes my session :(. I don't understand what's happening.

Comment: The task is not as simple as it seems. Since Python is not a parallel language by itself you needs some other engine which makes that translation. For Koalas that is Apache Spark.

Answer (score 1):

The real answer is hidden in comments, so I will add this answer: [use `mapply`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60758984/pandas-apply-in-parallel-when-axis-0#comment114299401_60758984).

```
import pandas as pd
import mapply

mapply.init(n_workers=-1, chunk_size=1)

def my_sum(x, a):
    return x + a

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]})
df.mapply(lambda x: my_sum(x, 2), axis=0)
```

I tried `swifter` and `pandarallel`, but `swifter` simply didn't work with columns, and `pandarallel` seemed to duplicate the work on all workers. Only `mapply` worked.

Comment: not sure if it was intentional, but you have n_workers set to -1, this didn't work for me and threw very confusing errors until I set n_workers to a positive number

Comment: actually turns out that it works on Linux, but I wasn't able to get it to work on Windows

Answer (score 0):

You can use the dask delayed interface to set up a custom workflow:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import distributed

# start local cluster, by default one worker per core
client = distributed.Client() 

@dask.delayed
def my_sum(x, a):
    return x + a

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]})    

# Here, we mimic the apply command. However, we do not
# actually run any computation. Instead, that line of code 
# results in a list of delayed objects, which contain the 
# information what computation should be performed eventually
delayeds = [my_sum(df[column], 2) for column in df.columns]

# send the list of delayed objects to the cluster, which will 
# start computing the result in parallel. 
# It returns future objects, pointing to the computation while
# it is still running
futures = client.compute(delayeds)

# get all the results, as soon as they are ready. This returns 
# a list of pandas Series objects, each is one column of the 
# output dataframe
computed_columns = client.gather(futures)

# create dataframe out of individual columns
computed_df = pd.concat(computed_columns, axis = 1)
```

Alternatively, you could also use the multiprocessing backend of dask:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask

@dask.delayed
def my_sum(x, a):
    return x + a

df = pd.DataFrame({'num_legs': [2, 4, 8, 0],
                   'num_wings': [2, 0, 0, 0]})    

# same as above
delayeds = [my_sum(df[column], 2) for column in df.columns]

# run the computation using the dask's multiprocessing backend
computed_columns = dask.compute(delayeds, scheduler = 'processes')

# create dataframe out of individual columns
computed_df = pd.concat(computed_columns, axis = 1)
```

Comment: distributed.Client() freezes my session. Maybe due to this issue:  https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/5525

Comment: `distributed.Client()` is a convenience method, which unfortunately causes trouble sometimes. You could either go through the effort to set up a cluster ['the hard way'](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#setup-dask-distributed-the-hard-way) (actually not that hard, you need to run two commands in the terminal) or use the multiprocessing backend instead (see my edit in two minutes)

Comment: dask.compute never ends now. I didn't say, I am on windows 10, code in VScode and have AMD Ryzen processor.

Comment: @Mislav maybe there is a problem whenever you try to spawn new processes from within your session. can you try setting up the cluster on the terminal and then connect to the scheduler from within your session? Have a look here about how to do it: https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#setup-dask-distributed-the-hard-way.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this case should be tackled focusing on how the data is split over the available resources. [Dask](https://dask.org/) offers [`map_partitions`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.map_partitions) which applies a Python function on each DataFrame partition. Of course, the number of rows per partition that your workstation can deal with depends on the available hardware resources. Here is an example based on the information you provided in your question:

```
# imports
import dask
from dask import dataframe as dd
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# range for values to be randomly generated
range_ = {
    "min": 0,
    "max": 100
}

# rows and columns for the fake dataframe
df_shape = (
                int(1e8), # rows
                2 # columns
            )

# some fake data
data_in = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(range_["min"], range_["max"], size = df_shape), columns = ["legs", "wings"])

# function to apply adding some value a to the partition
def my_sum(x, a):
    return x + a
"""
applies my_sum on the partitions rowwise (axis = 0)

number of partitions = cpu_count

the scheduler can be:
"threads": Uses a ThreadPool in the local process
"processes": Uses a ProcessPool to spread work between processes
"single-threaded": Uses a for-loop in the current thread
"""
data_out = dd.from_pandas(data_in, npartitions = mp.cpu_count()).map_partitions(
        lambda df: df.apply(
            my_sum, axis = 0, a = 2
        )
).compute(scheduler = "threads")

# inspection
print(data_in.head(5))
print(data_out.head(5))
```

This implementation was tested on a random generated dataframe with 100,000,000 rows and 2 columns.

**Workstation Specs**
**CPU:** Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz
**Memory Total:** 16698340 kB
**OS:** Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS